# HTML: Changing colors of specific words in a string of text

Tags: html, css, text, colors, inline

I have the below message (slightly changed):

> "Enter the competition by January 30, 2011 and you could win up to
>   $$$$ — including amazing summer trips!"

I currently have:

```
<p style="font-size:14px; color:#538b01; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;">
```

formatting the text string, but want to change the color of "January 30, 2011" to #FF0000 and "summer" to #0000A0.

How do I do this strictly with HTML or inline CSS?

Answer (score 193):

```
<p style="font-size:14px; color:#538b01; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;">
  Enter the competition by 
  <span style="color: #ff0000">January 30, 2011</span>
  and you could win up to $$$$ — including amazing 
  <span style="color: #0000a0">summer</span> 
  trips!
</p>
```

Or you may want to use CSS classes instead:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      p { 
        font-size:14px; 
        color:#538b01; 
        font-weight:bold; 
        font-style:italic;
      }
      .date {
        color: #ff0000;
      }
      .season { /* OK, a bit contrived... */
        color: #0000a0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Enter the competition by 
      <span class="date">January 30, 2011</span>
      and you could win up to $$$$ — including amazing 
      <span class="season">summer</span> 
      trips!
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a great answer! Easily demonstrates that the dots represent tags inside the paragraph tags. It really clarifies this information for anyone working with <style>.

Comment: Can this be done based on the index of the string? I mean like from character x to character y, how can I color it?

Comment: @DebjyotiBanerjee you cannot style text nodes with CSS, only elements. The only way to modify each character's color is to wrap each character in its own element, like with `<span/>`.

Answer (score 70):

You could use the HTML5 Tag `<mark>`:

```html
<p>Enter the competition by 
<mark class="red">January 30, 2011</mark> and you could win up to $$$$ — including amazing 
<mark class="blue">summer</mark> trips!</p>
```

And use this in the CSS:

```css
p {
    font-size:14px;
    color:#538b01;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
}

mark.red {
    color:#ff0000;
    background: none;
}

mark.blue {
    color:#0000A0;
    background: none;
}
```

The tag `<mark>` has a default background color... at least in Chrome.

Comment: A pity that the answer was not awarded. I would have awarded it to this (and fie upon those who use browsers that don't support HTML (are there still any?))

Comment: A simple and effective solution that does no more, and no less, than the OP requested.

Comment: The mark tag is not meant to be used for formatting.

Comment: The mark tag adds some padding at the beginning and end of the text, so the class needs to have `margin:0;` in it. This is evidence that it's for highlighing, not general formatting, for which the span tag is better-suited.

Answer (score 41):

```
<p style="font-size:14px; color:#538b01; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;">
    Enter the competition by <span style="color:#FF0000">January 30, 2011</span> and you could win up to $$$$ — including amazing <span style="color:#0000A0">summer</span> trips!
</p>
```

The span elements are inline an thus don't break the flow of the paragraph, only style in between the tags.

Answer (score 31):

use spans. ex) `<span style='color: #FF0000;'>January 30, 2011</span>`

Answer (score 27):

```
<font color="red">This is some text!</font>
```

This worked the best for me when I only wanted to change one word into the color red in a sentence.

Comment: <font color="red">This is some text!</font>

Comment: This is not supported in HTML 5.

Comment: Deprecated: This feature is no longer recommended. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font

Answer (score 6):

You can also make a class:

`<span class="mychangecolor"> I am in yellow color!!!!!!</span>`

then in a css file do:

```
.mychangecolor{ color:#ff5 /* it changes to yellow */ }
```

Answer (score 6):

Tailor this code however you like to fit your needs, you can select text? in the paragraph to be what font or style you need!:

```
<head>
<style>
p{ color:#ff0000;font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;} 
font{color:#000fff;background:#000000;font-size:225%;}
b{color:green;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is your <b>text. <font>Type</font></strong></b>what you like</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use the longer boringer way

```html
<p style="font-size:14px; color:#538b01; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;">Enter the competition by</p><p style="font-size:14px; color:#ff00; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;">summer</p>
```

you get the point for the rest