# How to set color to some portion of text in radio.setLabel("Phone Number"+cont.getPhone);

Tags: java, jquery, html, css, zk

I am using Zk framework for UI and from Controller side i need to set the value for the radio.Have a look on below code

```
radio.setLabel("Phone Number#"+"<span style="+"\" foreground-color:blue \""+">"+cont.getPhone().toString() +"</span>"+"Email Id"+cont.getEmail());
```

but it is not replacing the color,only color of phone number should be replaced

Answer (score 0):

Try below line of code

If you want to do in ZUl page try this

```
 <radio id="radiog" label="Item D" value="itemD" style="color:blue;"/>
```

otherwise try

```
radio.setStyle("color:blue;");//Their can be syntax error please modify it according to your requirement.
```

Comment: Only color of Phone number should change but with this everything is changing.

Comment: Please change specific radio from RadioGroup not all the radio button

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my fiddle. I separate your radio in 3 components: 1 radio and 2 labels, all inside 1 div. This is the only *simple* way I can think of

[Fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/22ln554/2-radio-custom-color)

Code

```
<zk>
  <window border="normal" title="hello">

    <div>
          <radio id="radio" value="itemD" />
          <label value="Phone: " />
          <label style="color:blue" value="123456" />
    </div>
  </window>
</zk>
```

Comment: Hii my zul is <h:table><h:tr><radiogroup id="multipleMatchesRgId"/></h:tr></h:table> and from controller side i need to set more than one label to radio and in that only phone number should be colored

Answer (score 0):

I doubt ZK allows use of HTML code inside the radiobutton label.

I suggest breaking it into smaller pieces like @AlexGreg answer shows, you can even consider using spans or try a CSS approach like the one suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4622818/1385048.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the client widget's implementation **domLabel_()** function  as follows:

```
<radio xmlns:w="client">
    <attribute name="onCreate"><![CDATA[
    self.setLabel("<span style='color:blue'>test</span>");
    ]]></attribute>
    <attribute w:name="domLabel_">
    function () { return this.getLabel(); }
    </attribute>
</radio>
```

Comment: I tried this but on browser its displaying complete html but not the color plz help

Answer (score 0):

i acheived this through a piece of code.

first create Outer Hlayout then radio button then inner hlayout 
created two label's & then set css seperatly
set that lable to inner hlayout, 
inner hlayout to radio
and radio to outerlayout.