# How to color specific word inside paragraph tag?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to color a specific word inside a paragraph. Is there a way to make that happen?

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Say in `<p>Hello World</p>`, I want to color the word "World" inside the paragraph.

Is there a way to do it?

To make things clear here is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Unless nesting the specific word into a `<span>`, I cannot see how to do it.

Comment: Are you asking for the HTML tags to achieve this or the PHP code do this dynamically for varying words?

Comment: yes I am trying to find code that all word "World" inside paragraph must be green regardless how many word "World" is inside so all of them must be green

Comment: Then you need the solution of @Rasel.

Comment: Since you need to highlight each instance, take a look at this duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501007/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-style-parts-of-all-instances-of-a-specific-word

Comment: If your asking for HTML tags to achieve this, there are already answers to this question like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4622818/1648849).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$paragraph = "Hello World";
$paragraph = str_replace('World', '<span class="highlightClass">World</span>', $paragraph);
echo '<p>'.$paragraph.'</p>';
```

**css**

```
.highlightClass{
color:green;
}
```

Comment: This might be what he wanted.. but he wasn't clear.. a styled span looks like what he is going for, as David answered.. OP needs to clarify..

Comment: This is the way to go. Also consider using HTML5 `<mark>` instead of `<span>`

Answer (score 4):

Use the SPAN TAG

`<p>Hello <span style='color:green'>world</span></p>`

Comment: Who downvoted this? This is exactly what the guy asked for lol

Comment: yes but I have a <p> Hello World </p> but my paragraph might contain a lot of world that is repeated so I will put that span in every word I want to put can we have it like all word "World" inside paragraph must be green

Comment: @BrandonJakeSullano I think you need to clarify your answer. What both David and Rasel answered, do what your asking.

Comment: Next time please be more clear on what you want. If you want to do this dynamically, please say DYNAMICALLY, if you're just asking for hard HTML, then state HTML

Comment: yes I am 4 days old here more rooms for improvements thanks dude :)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using javascript also

check this example

```
<style>
.green{
    color:green;
}
</style>
<div id="paragraph">

</div>
<script>
var mystring = "This is a very long paragraph with some green words highlighted with green color. green, green, green"
mystring = mystring.replace(new RegExp("green", 'g'), "<span class='green'>green</span>");
document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML=mystring;
</script>
```

It will apply styling to all words in the paragraph provided

Check out JSfiddle Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/t9e04sgv/