# How to change a color of a piece of text in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use jQuery to change `h1` header after end of a game and I have the following line of code:

```
$('h1').text(winningPlayer+" has won!").css("fontSize", "55px");
```

The question is, how can I set a different color just for `winningPlayer` part of text??

Comment: You'd have to put `winningPlayer` inside of an element you can then style, like `span`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML: Changing colors of specific words in a string of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622808/html-changing-colors-of-specific-words-in-a-string-of-text)

Comment: use <span></span>

Comment: @LucaKiebel: Before i posted my question I have read the answers for the question you linked. There was no answer for my question. The answer I got from Maheer Ali is perfect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the `winningPlayer` in `<span>` and change `.text()` to `.html()`. Below is the demo

```js
let winningPlayer = "John"
$('h1').html(`<span style="color:blue">${winningPlayer}</span> has won!`).css("fontSize", "55px");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1></h1>
```