# i want to change 3 dfferent type of font color in php

Tags: php, css, colors, fonts, multiple-columns

I am new to PHP my query is I have a row where are 3 columns binding and I want to give each columns different colors I have tried so many things but still am not be able to achieve what I want so brother please help me how can I do this I will be really thankful to your all guys.

```
here is my code :
    echo '<li> 
            <label-1 for="subfolder2">' . $category["account_no"] . "-".$category['account_name'] ."-". "(" . $category['closing_account'] . ")" . '</label-1> 
            <input type="checkbox" id="subfolder2"/>';
```

Thanks

Comment: do you have any css?

Comment: yes i have  but there are no option for changing just once i change the color that color apply for all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML: Changing colors of specific words in a string of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622808/html-changing-colors-of-specific-words-in-a-string-of-text)

Comment: no its different

Comment: can anyone tell me which query i need to put in my CSS so it will work for me

Comment: why is it different?

Comment: because am not using any tag of html

Comment: _Small Note_ There is no `<label-1>` tag in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the 3 values are what you call the 3 columns.

You can use the `<span>` tag and some inline styling

```
echo '<li>
<label for="subfolder2">
        <span style="color:red">' . $category["account_no"] . '</span>
        -
        <span style="color:blue">'.$category['account_name'] .  '</span>
        -
        <span style="color:green"> (' 
            . $category['closing_account'] . ')</span>
</label>';
```