# How do I change text color when I have a universal font color set?

Tags: html, text, colors, fonts

How do I change the text color for a specific piece of text when I have a text color set inside the body tag. It doesn't seem to work. Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way of going around this?

```html
<body style="background-color: black; color: white">
<p>Hello!</p>
```

Hope this wasn't confusing as I am not the best at explaining things!

Comment: The "better" way of doing this is to use a stylesheet instead of inline styles. Even `<style>body { background-color: black; color: white; } p { color: red; }</style>` would be better. But I see no code where you're trying to set a text color for a specific piece of text...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML: Changing colors of specific words in a string of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622808/html-changing-colors-of-specific-words-in-a-string-of-text)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question right, you want to change the color of the "Hello!", but not the rest of the body? If so, you can just use a seperate style for the p tag:

```
<p style="color: red">Hello!</p>
```

Sorry, if I didn't understand the question properly.

Comment: You understood me... Turns out I made a typo and didn't realise it like always lol ‍♂️