# Styling a specific sentence in a paragraph with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to only target this specific sentence (Starting at $2.00 / frame.) in a paragraph to apply CSS and it has to remain in the same line but when using other elements it skips one line.

```
<p>Assorted frames made of different material, including MDF, birchwood, and PDE. Select frames can be sanded and painted according to your needs. Starting at $2.00 / frame.</p>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML: Changing colors of specific words in a string of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622808/html-changing-colors-of-specific-words-in-a-string-of-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just wrap your targeted element in `span` tag and apply style.**

```css
p .highlight {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>Assorted frames made of different material, including MDF, birchwood, and PDE. Select frames can be sanded and painted according to your needs. Starting at <span class="highlight"> $2.00 / frame. </span> </p>
```

**[Note]** Change style according to your need.

Comment: but it will change all span property inside p it's better make a class or call it inside those span in which it needed.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could put them inside of a span tag because it is an inline element and will not change the behaviour of the whole line.
Then you can target the span however you want or putting a class on that span or selecting it as a child from that paragraph.

How it was useful.

```
<p>Your text here <span class"special-text">Starting at $2.00 / frame.</span> more text </p>
```

then on CSS

```
.special-text{
  your styling
}
```

or

```
p > .special-text{
  your styling
}
```