# Is there a way to output text or string in an html pre tag from a string builder with styling?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, stringbuilder, diffplex

I am using a **Diffplex** tool to compare two strings to see which words have been added, deleted etc. I can get the words or sentences which have been added or deleted with ease and display them in an html `pre` tag. What I was using is appending a `+` and `-` using `string builder` on words added and removed respectively and indeed its showing without a problem. The code is below;

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        string oldText = OldContent;
        string newText = newContent;

        var d = new Differ();
        var builder = new InlineDiffBuilder(d);
        var result = builder.BuildDiffModel(oldText, newText);

        foreach (var line in result.Lines)
        {
            if (line.Type == ChangeType.Inserted)
            {
                sb.Append("+ ");
            }
            else if (line.Type == ChangeType.Deleted)
            {
                sb.Append("- ");
            }
            else if (line.Type == ChangeType.Modified)
            {
                sb.Append("* ");
            }
            else if (line.Type == ChangeType.Imaginary)
            {
                sb.Append("? ");
            }
            else if (line.Type == ChangeType.Unchanged)
            {
                //sb.Append("  ");
            }

        sb.Append(line.Text + "\n");
        ViewBag.result = sb.ToString();
```

I am returning the string to an html pre tag like below;

```
<pre>@ViewBag.result</pre>
```

Below is a sample output of the result

`+ This line has been added`

`- This line has been deleted`

The `+` and `-` are showing at the start of the sentences without a problem. Now My question; Is it possible to output a sentence or words which I am appending the `+` symbol green and the one with `-` symbol red? If so how can I approach this and can I append the styling using the string builder then send it and If so how can I approach this?

Comment: HTML is text with tags.  See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622808/html-changing-colors-of-specific-words-in-a-string-of-text?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by rendering the string as html using tag helpers in the view like below. I added span tags and gave them an ID which I am using for the colors;

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    string oldText = Document.OldContent;
    string newText = Document.Contents;

    var d = new Differ();
    var builder = new InlineDiffBuilder(d);
    var result = builder.BuildDiffModel(oldText, newText);

    foreach (var line in result.Lines)
    {
        if (line.Type == ChangeType.Inserted)
        {
            sb.Append("<span id=\"added\">+ ");
        }
        else if (line.Type == ChangeType.Deleted)
        {
            sb.Append("<span id=\"removed\">- ");
        }
        else if (line.Type == ChangeType.Modified)
        {
            sb.Append("<span id=\"modified\">* ");
        }
        else if (line.Type == ChangeType.Imaginary)
        {
            sb.Append("<span id=\"imaginary\">? ");
        }
        else if (line.Type == ChangeType.Unchanged)
        {
            //sb.Append("<span id=\"unchanged\">  ");
        }

        sb.Append(line.Text + "</span> \n");
    }
ViewBag.result = sb.ToString();
```

The tag helpers in the view;

```
@using System.Net
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Rendering my string as html;

```
@Html.Raw(@WebUtility.HtmlDecode(ViewBag.result))
```

Styling with the classes;

```
<style>
#added {
    background-color: lawngreen;
}

#removed {
    background-color: indianred;
}

#modified {
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
```